# Mysql Procedure out negative value

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have make a procedure where two queries return values for

> a and b

Substract of a and b is c

```
c = a-b;
```

if value of c is positive then procedure return correct value and if value of c is in negative then procedure return NULL.

This is my procedure.

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `db`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `getOutStandingBalance`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `getOutStandingBalance`(OUT Total DOUBLE SIGNED,IN OID INT)
    DETERMINISTIC
    COMMENT 'A procedure'
BEGIN
    DECLARE Credit DOUBLE;
    DECLARE Debit  DOUBLE;
    SELECT SUM(transaction.Amount) INTO Credit FROM `transaction` WHERE transaction.IsDeleted=0 AND transaction.IsCredit=1 AND transaction.OID=OID;

    SELECT SUM(transaction.Amount) INTO Debit FROM `transaction` WHERE transaction.IsDeleted=0 AND transaction.IsCredit=0 AND transaction.OID=OID;

    SET Total = (Credit-Debit);
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: do you need to know which records have null values? or do you only need the records where the value of c is positive. If you only the records where c is positive you can limit your query to where a>=b. Otherwise a case statement should work.

Comment: OP asks why procedure is returning a NULL though a and b are valid.

Comment: @DaveyBoy my question is how can i get negative values out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If no rows are found for either of the credit or debit for the transaction, the variables will be `NULL`. In SQL, any calculation with a `NULL` results in a `NULL`.

To fix, do this:

```
SET Total = ifnull(Credit, 0) - ifnull(Debit, 0);
```

Also, change the signature to

```
OUT Total decimal(16,2)
```

or similar. Why are you using `DOUBLE SIGNED`?

Comment: it dose't return negative value returns unsigned number and i need negative number if it return negative.

Comment: i have tried decimal and the output is same then i tried double with signed may be return a negative value like `-20`